# Clojurescript macro and name mangling

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

**Context**

I am using Clojurescript and I am trying to define a lot of functions at compile time to wrap a Javascript API. My code works fine with lower level of optimization of the compiler. Yes, when I use the `:optimizations :advanced` Clojurescript compiler flag, the compiler throws warning: `Use of undeclared Var my.namespace/fname` and my code does not work at runtime (some mangled symbol not found).

**Here is a minimum example of the issue:**

```clj
(defmacro create-a-function [l]
  `(defn ~l [o#] (inc o#)))

(create-a-function fname)

;; Below inside another function
(defn fname-clone [k]
  (fname k))
```

I decide a function called `fname` at compile-time using the macro `create-a-function`. When I try to call the function at runtime it fails.

**What have I tried?**

- Lower optimization level: it works
- Tested that the macro works fine at the repl
- Using declare, like `(declare fname)`, which gets rid of the warning at compile time but fails at runtime with the same error.

**My question**

How can I make this kind of code work with advanced level of optimization?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your problem. I copy pasted your code and it works correctly here under advanced optimization. I assume you did put the macro in a separate clj or cljc file and import using require-macros? Also, what version of clojurescript are you running? I am on clojurescript 1.10.238 with shadow-cljs. I don't think shadow-cljs makes a difference here though..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reproduced your code in [this repo](https://github.com/borkdude/cljs-macro) and it works.

Note that you have to put your macro in a `.clj` file.

When you want to use macros from a `.cljc` file in ClojureScript, use [macrovich](https://github.com/cgrand/macrovich).

Comment: Thank you, that was it, I put the macro in a `.cljc` file

Comment: Updated the answer for .cljc files.